# How to add condition to COALESCE while reading xml in Sql

Tags: sql-server, xml, xquery-sql

I am trying to read the xml and storing it in SQL server.

```
DECLARE @xml XML
SET @xml = 
 '<report>
    <personal>
       <search>
           <subject>
               <name>SearchName</name>
           </subject>
       </search>    
    </personal>
    <personal>
       <search>
           <subject>
               <name>SearchName</name>
           </subject>
       </search>
       <result>
           <history>
              <name>HistoryName</name>
           </history>
       </result>
    </personal>
    <personal>
       <search>
           <subject>
               <name>SearchName</name>
           </subject>
       </search>
       <result>
           <history>
              <dob>HistoryDOB</dob>
           </history>
       </result>
    </personal>
  </report>
'
```

What i am trying here is - selecting the name but condition here is

1. if `<personal>` contains `<result>` then select the `name` under `history/name`
2. if `<personal>` doesn't contain `<result>` select the `name` under `subject/name`
3. if `<personal>` contain `<result>`BUT name is not there then enter null

I am using below query

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(
   A.Search.value('(result/history/name)[1]','varchar(max)'),
   A.Search.value('(search/subject/name)[1]','varchar(max)')
) AS Name
FROM @xml.nodes('/report/personal') as A(Search)
```

It is returning

```
 SearchName
 HistoryName
 SearchName
```

But it is failing in 3rd condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tweak the second `values` call to specifically request what you've specified - that you'll only take a `search/subject` for nodes with no `result`:

```
SELECT 
COALESCE(
   A.Search.value('(result/history/name)[1]','varchar(max)'),
   A.Search.value('(search[not(../result)]/subject/name)[1]','varchar(max)')
) AS Name
FROM @xml.nodes('/report/personal') as A(Search)
```

Result:

```
Name
------------------
HistoryName
SearchName
NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [exist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869(v=sql.120).aspx) method to chech if `<personal>` contains `<result>` or not.

Using it your algorithm can be straightforward translated to query as:

```
select
    case 
        when A.Search.exist('result') = 1
            then A.Search.value('(result/history/name)[1]','varchar(max)')
        else A.Search.value('(search/subject/name)[1]','varchar(max)')
    end as Name
FROM @xml.nodes('/report/personal') as A(Search)
```